# Swift: Issue saving `List` object into realm database and subsequent tableView update when inserting a new row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

## Introduction

**Context:**

I'm coding up one of my first apps in which I want to be able to add a new row on a button press at index 0, (see code below). I use realm database to store my data.

**Issue**

- Pressing the add button I have triggers the following crash `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'.`
- Also when I check print statements of my tableView data array `eventArray` its always nil. Which leads me to believe that I'm not actually succeeding in saving data to realm.

**Question:**

Why isn't the data saved to my realm database? And why can't my tableView insert a new row?

## Code

I've commented the points where my issues happen

```
class EventsScreen: UIViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var eventArray : EventList?

    @objc func addEvent() {    //The function my add button calls when pressed
       let newCell = Event()
       print(realm.objects(EventList.self).first)
       insertInRealmContainerAtIndexZero(newEvent: newCell)
       print(realm.objects(EventList.self).first)
       let ndxPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

       tableView.beginUpdates()
       tableView.insertRows(at: [ndxPath], with: .bottom)   //App terminates on this line
       tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       loadEvents()
       setupBackgroundVisuals()
       registerCellAndDelegateAndDataSource()
    }

    private func insertInRealmContainerAtIndexZero(newEvent: Event) {   // I suspect this method is the problem since when I restart the app the tableview doesn't load up any new created events.
       if eventArray?.events != nil {
          do {
              try realm.write {
                 eventArray?.events.insert(newEvent, at: 0)   
             }
          } catch {
              print(error)
          }
       } else {
          do {
              try realm.write {
                  realm.add(newEvent)
             }
          } catch {
             print(error)
         }
       }

   }

    private func loadEvents() {
         eventArray = realm.objects(EventList.self).first
         tableView.beginUpdates()
         tableView.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

**Data object:**

```
class Event: Object {
    @objc dynamic var eventTitle: String?
    @objc dynamic var eventText: String?
}

class EventList: Object {
    let events = List<Event>()
}
```

Thanks for reading my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First time you launch the app this line

```
eventArray = realm.objects(EventList.self).first
```

returns nil and when run this

```
if eventArray?.events != nil {
```

it goes to else as `eventArray` is nil , then in else you do

```
realm.add(newEvent)
```

despite you should

```
eventArray  =  EventList()

eventArray.events.append(newEvent)
```

then add

```
realm.add(eventArray)
```

Comment: I've tried for almost 8 Hours but your answer is working a charm. thanks for this.